# Как понять что обновление системы linux не зависло?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Командой   do release upgrade
запустил обновление системы.
А дальше уже 3 часа ничего не меняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно как то понять что обновление идёт или только ждать?
Есть ли какие то логи куда пишется то что делает linux-headers-4.18?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 ps aux | grep dpkg
root     10605  0.0  0.0   2560   820 pts/1    S+   10:40   0:00 /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic.postinst configure
manking  17908  0.0  0.0   8864   900 pts/2    S+   14:40   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn dpkg
root     22281  0.0  0.0  20968 11576 pts/1    Ss+  10:39   0:01 /usr/bin/dpkg --force-overwrite --status-fd 115 --configure --pending
```

Comment: может просмотр использование ресурсов поможет?

Comment: А что именно нужно посмотреть?

Comment: Жрёт ли кто-нибудь связанный с обновлением какие-нибудь ресурсы. Если жрёт — значит не зависло )

Comment: Вы это случайно не в VirtualBox запускаете? У меня виртуалка тоже на этом месте задумывалась, тоже приходилось много часов ждать

Comment: Нет. Мощный рабочий ноутбук core i7 ssd. Но много разных программ и пакетов было  установлено.

Comment: Тогда действительно странно, на ssd такое тем более должно за несколько секунд пролетать. Но всё же скорее всего не зависло, а затормозило по какой-то причине, но это вряд ли удастся точно диагностировать

Comment: Выводит ли команда `ps aux | grep dpkg` что-нибудь?

Comment: Ну команда  lsb_release -a

показывает что установлена новая версия системы.

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.10
Release: 18.10
Codename: cosmic

Comment: в вопросе разместил вывод  команды ps aux | grep dpkg

Comment: Ну, пока мне остаётся только посоветовать ждать.) // «Есть ли какие то логи» — вряд ли, потому что скорее всего подтупило что-то, что не занимается ведением логов. можно посоветовать поглядеть `/var/log/dpkg.log` или `dmesg`, и убедиться в наличии свободного места `df -h`, но вряд ли там есть что-то интересное

Comment: А что будет если перезагрузиться?

Comment: Будет не до конца обновлённая система. Чем это обернётся — как повезёт, может быть ничего страшного, а может полная неработоспособность системы — в зависимости от того, что обновление успело или не успело сделать. Если вы никуда не спешите и/или не умеете ремонтировать поломанную систему, я бы посоветовал ещё подождать. Когда совсем надоест, можно попробовать прервать обновление через Ctrl+C (или через kill, если на Ctrl+C не реагирует) и запустить его ещё раз (без перезагрузки), но опять же будет не до конца обновлённая система и это как повезёт

Comment: Перезагрузил. Дошел до экрана ввода логина и было видно что там не хватает иконок, текста и графики. То есть битая установка. После ввода логина черный экран и огромный курсор. Потом через минуту опять переходит на экран логина. Потом загрузился в режиме восстановления и запустил там опцию восстановления поврежденных пакетов. Он как раз продолжил с того места на котором остановился и все до установил. Сейчас загрузился нормально уже. Все программы работают, но ядро старое 4.15.0-46-generic

Comment: Повезло. Запустите обновление ещё раз, по идее должно доустановиться ядро и всё остальное (если снова не зависнет, хех)

Comment: Да, всё доустановил. Ядро тоже поставил новое. Но драйвер nvidia снес и режимы видеокарты. Доступен только режим 960x540

Comment: Возможно всё повисло из-за того что было открыто много других приложений во время обновления системы, google хром, ide, slack и.т.д.
И он какие то файлы не смог обновить.